# Clang C Compiler 'class' keyword reserved?

Tags: c, xcode, ffmpeg, clang

Hi I am compiling ffmpeg using xcode, which I believe uses clang for compilation. In ffmpeg there is a struct with a member variable named 'class' I believe this is perfectly fine in C but clang is trying to parse it as a keyword. Any idea how to fix? Basically the following in a cpp file will cause the error:

```
extern C {
    typedef struct {
        int class;
    } SomeStruct;
}
```

It tries to interpret class as a keyword.

FYI the file that is throwing the error in ffmpeg is libavcodec/mpegvideo.h and I need to include this to have access to the MpegEncContext struct to pull out motion map info.

*EDIT*

The above code sample was just to demonstrate the error. But perhaps its fixable in another way. In my actual code I have it like this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    #include "libavcodec/mpegvideo.h"
    #include "libavformat/avformat.h"

#if __cplusplus
} //Extern C
#endif
```

How would I get that to include the two files as C files and not C++?

Thanks

Comment: And your Xcode- (ffmpeg) related question is:

Comment: hehe: `extern COBOL { ADD A TO B GIVING C }`

Comment: My xcode ffmpeg related question is, how do I include that header into a c++ file and compile it in Xcode?

Comment: There is no way to use such declarations in C++. You need to massage the sources (renaming that member everywhere) or write a wrapper in C with visible interface that does not conflict with C++. You may or may not be able to play some tricks with macros (I'm not familiar with those sources so I'm not sure if the macro tricks are easily doable or not).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's completely fine in C. When you build that as C++, you encounter an error because `class` is a C++ keyword.

As far as fixing it, you would normally choose an identifier other than `class`. However, ffmpeg developers may not be so agreeable with that change. Therefore, you may need to either:

- restrict the visibility of that header to C translations
- or edit your own copy in order to use it in C++ translations

Fortunately, you are also using a C compiler which has good support of C99 features in this case. C Compilers which do not support C99 well are particularly troublesome with ffmpeg sources (because you would then compile the whole program as C++ for the C99 features, and the conflict count would be much higher).

(there are other dirty tricks you *could* do to try to work around the problem, but i will not mention them)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how I can restrict the visibility of those headers to C translations? I suppose I could move any code that uses that file into a .c file instead. But I would still have to include that .c file from a c++ file at some point I believe.

Comment: I guess I could just rename class variable to anything else since its only using the header file for reference (ffmpeg is already compiled into a library) but I just don't like messing with the source files if I don't have to, makes updating a bit harder.

Comment: @user1689196 sure. you're on the right track; you would need create either a thin wrapper layer (in C) which you can then call from C++ for interacting with `SomeStruct`, or just deal with that aspect of the program which includes `SomeStruct` exclusively in a larger C implementation.

Comment: @user1689196 and yes, it certainly can complicate updating, builds, and maintenance but... you just have to choose what you see as the lesser-evil (unless somebody comes up with a better solution). the first option is safer, but requires more work up front. the second requires more maintenance over time and is often more likely to introduce errors. of course, you might want to just grab clean checkouts each stable release, then edit that (throwing your changes away every few months). it's no fun :)

Answer (score 4):

> Basically the following in a cpp file will cause the error

.cpp files are processed as C++ files, not C, and `class` is a reserved word in C++.

Comment: but shouldn't extern C force it to use the C compiler?

Comment: @user1689196, absolutely not.  That will just change the linkage of symbols to stop name mangling.  You can force the language by using the -x flag.

Comment: No, `extern C` just changes how name mangling works.  To compile as C, use .c

Comment: Hmm, then how do you usually do this. In reality, I'm just including the ffmpeg header files, not actually declaring a struct inline. And it still gives me the error.

Comment: @user1689196: you write C functions that handle FFmpeg code for you, then declare and call those in C++ without ever including the actual FFmpeg headers in C++ source code.

Comment: Thanks @larsman I believe that's the basic answer I was looking for.

Comment: @user1689196 Since justin just said the same, you might want to accept his answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a choice to rename anything in those header files, you could just replace the `class` token by something else

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
# define class videoClass
#endif

    #include "libavcodec/mpegvideo.h"
    #include "libavformat/avformat.h"

#if __cplusplus
# undef class
} //Extern C
#endif
```

This is quite a dirty hack, but for such badly interfaced code you don't have much choice. The real solution would be to have all the `struct` members in these files use names that us some sort of prefix or so, as it is done in the network layer code. There all members have some prefixes as `ss_` or `sa_` and such problems are very unlikely to occur.

Comment: this is the primary dirty trick i had in mind when i wrote about dirty tricks in my answer :) *(don't worry, i won't downvote because you actually went through the trouble of pointing out and explaining the problem, and made it clear that it's dirty)*